# Prove that a square-integrable entire function is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, entire-functions

> Suppose $f$ is entire and 
>   $$\iint_\mathbb{C}|f(z)|^2dxdy < \infty$$Prove that $f\equiv 0.$

So far I have:

*Suppose $f$ is bounded.*  Then $f$ is constant by virtue of Liouville and so the conclusion is obvious.  Thus, assume $f$ non-bounded.  Then 
$$\Big|\iint_\mathbb{C}f^2(z)dA\Big| \leq \iint_\mathbb{C}|f(z)|^2dxdy < \infty$$
We can parameterize
\begin{align*} \iint_\mathbb{C}f^2(z)dA &= \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}f^2(re^{i\theta})\;d\theta\;rdr \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}f^2(re^{i\theta})\;ire^{i\theta}[-i\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}]d\theta\;rdr \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\oint_{C_R}f^2(z)\;[-i\frac{1}{z}]dz\;rdr \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}2\pi r dr\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_R}\frac{f^2(z)}{z}dz \\ \\
&= 2\pi f^2(0)\int_0^\infty rdr 
\end{align*}

Whence f(0) = 0.  And I have no idea where to go from there.

The "entire" bit seems to suggest Liouville but I have already dealt with the bounded case.  Please advise ...

Comment: Try to consider the translation $g(z)=f(z-z_0)$.

Comment: How do you get the expression in the second line following the words "we can parametrize"?

Comment: @user254665 I made an error with parentheses, now corrected.

Comment: @XiangYu But of course.  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Fix $z_0\in \Bbb C$. For all $r > 0$, $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\, d\theta$$ By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2 \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\, d\theta$$ for all $r > 0$. Hence, for every $R > 0$,

$$\int_0^{R} \lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2 r\, dr \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2 r\, d\theta\, dr $$ or $$\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2 \frac{R^2}{2} \le  \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{D(z_0;R)} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2\, dx\, dy$$ Hence, $$\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2 \le \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\iint_{D(z_0;R)} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2\, dx\, dy\le \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\iint_{\Bbb C} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2\, dx\, dy \to 0\quad \text{as} \quad R\to \infty$$

So $f(z_0) = 0$. Since $z_0$ was arbitrary, $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Okay.  How is Cauchy-Schwarz applicable?  What is the inner product?  Is it
$$\langle u, v\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} uv$$ Since the functions are complex-valued it is not necessarily true that $$\langle v,u\rangle = \overline{\langle u, v\rangle}$$.  If $$\langle u, v\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} |uv|$$ then we don't have linearity in the first argument.

Comment: Think simpler than that. We have $4\pi^2 \lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2 \le \left(\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\, d\theta\right)^2$, and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$\left(\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\, d\theta\right)^2 \le \int_0^{2\pi} 1^2\, d\theta\cdot \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\, d\theta = 2\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\, d\theta$$ Dividing through by $4\pi^2$ yields the second line in the above answer.

Comment: @kobe It follows directly from $|f(z_0)|\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z_0+re^{i\theta})|d\theta$ and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have the seond line in your answer.

Comment: @user549397 that's how I did it originally, but I explained it to the OP in a different way.

Comment: @kobe But I can't see any reason why you have $4\pi^2|f(z_0)|^2\le \left( 
\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z_0+re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta \right)^2$.

Comment: @user549397 Sorry there are typos in that comment -- it's been a while since I last wrote it. What I meant to say in the comment was $4\pi^2 \lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2 \le (\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert\, d\theta)^2$, which is no greater than $$\int_0^{2\pi} 1^2\, d\theta \cdot \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\, d\theta = 2\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(z_0 + re^{i\theta}\rvert^2\, d\theta$$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Dividing through by $4\pi^2$ yields the second line.

Comment: @kobe That should be fine, I get it.