# Does there exist a non constant entire function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ which is square integrable?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

> Does there exist a non constant entire function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ which is [square integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) i.e. $\int_{\mathbb C} \vert f(z)\vert^2 dz< \infty$ ?

I think that answer to above question is no and this should be direct application(probably by power series expansion of $f$) of some theorem but i am unable to solve this.Any ideas?

Comment: this would imply $f^2$ is $L^1$ integrable (and entire), so i think you can drop the square. (or am I wrong? is the square root of an entire function not neccessairily entire?)

Comment: @max spaces of infinite measure satisfy the reverse containment

Comment: No, see here -http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822732/prove-that-a-complex-valued-entire-function-is-identically-zero

Comment: @Max, consider $z \to z$. It does not have an analytic square-root.

Comment: Dear @Hmm. Thank you! Is there any generalization of the problem(like in L^p spaces)?